# Hi! I am using Phantom JS to print my Google chart while printing multiple chart I can't get my X-axis co-ordinates?

Tags: google-visualization, phantomjs

I Created 4 Google chart for a report, it works fine and displays X, Y co-ordinates, but while printing it using phanthom JS I am getting the X axis co-ordinates only for the first chart not for the rest of the charts. Any Ideas || suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delay rendering as in the [raterize.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) example.

```
...
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: did you change the page.viewport size ?